# AdSense Management API (PHP) Get Payments

Tags: adsense-api

I'm trying to get the 'Balance' value from the API. Basically, I want to retrieve the amount that has not yet been paid.

So far, I have the sample API PHP working, but I can't figure out how to get the value above, or the "This Month" value that appears in the AdSense console.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured out how to get amount owing:

$result = $service->accounts_payments->listAccountsPayments($accountID);
  foreach ($result as $payment) {
    printf("Amount to be paid: %s\$%s\n", $payment['paymentAmountCurrencyCode'], $payment['paymentAmount']);
  }